# Using R script with Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark

I want to run my existing R script from Spark.

I have setup R and Spark on my machine and trying to execute the code but i am getting exception but that is not very helpful.

Spark Code-

```
String file = "/home/MSA2.R";
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("First App")
                .setMaster("local[1]");

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        JavaRDD<String> rdd = sparkContext.textFile("/home/test.csv")
        .pipe(file);
```

R code -

```
f1 <- read.csv("/home/testing.csv")
```

Exception -

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subprocess exited with status 2.
>   Command ran: /home/MSA2.R
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1
>   rg.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 >seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout at >org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTime‌​>out$$createRpcTimeou‌​tException(RpcTimeou‌​t.scala:48)

There is not much in exception to debug the issue.

Can anyone suggest if the approach is correct or not. If yes can anyone help with the issue, If no, please suggest an approach.

Note: I don't want to use Spark R

Reference of above code- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/executing-existing-r-scripts-from-spark-rutger-de-graaf

Comment: Can you share the entire exception trace?

Comment: @NishuTayal Updated.

Comment: Do you get any more information if you remove the Logger lines?

Comment: Additional Exception @Jorge
16/10/20 03:01:28 ERROR util.Utils: Exception encountered
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1
 at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:22)

org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)

Comment: @kushagramittal : Now, there is another error "java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1" ??

Comment: After removing below lines-

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF); Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

Got this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I have added

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

on the first line of the RScript and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Actual error is :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subprocess exited with status 2.
>   Command ran: /home/MSA2.R

Make sure, MSA2.R exists in the given location and in the same cluster where you are running spark jobs.

Generally exit status 2 occurs when script is not able to access the device.

Comment: The file is there

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 kushagra.mittal domain users  175 Oct 20 02:04 MSA2.R*